# Player life is increasing per frame instead of per second

Tags: c#

I am making a game and I added lives and score in it. Everything is ok but something I want to add is that if the score is multiple of 15 then lives increase by 1. 
The problem that I am having here is that the lives are increasing per frame and not per second. 60 frames per second, so it is increasing lives by 60 instead of 1.

The part that is working it is in 'update'

```
public class RobotDodge
{
   private Player _Player;
   private Window _GameWindow;
   private List<Robot> _Robots;
   //private int _Lives;
   private decimal _Score, _Lives;
   private DateTime _Time, currentTime;

   public bool Quit{
      get{
          return _Player.Quit;
         }
    }
    // making our game constructor..
    public RobotDodge(){
             _GameWindow=new Window("Robot Dodge", 800, 800);
             _Player=new Player(_GameWindow); 
             _Robots = new List<Robot>();
             _Lives = _Player._Lives; // player lives are 5.
             _Score = 0;
            //_Counter = 0;
            currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            _Time = DateTime.Now;
    }
    // method that returns our new Robot object..
    public Robot RandomRobot(){
          float r = SplashKit.Rnd();
          Boxy _Boxy=new Boxy(_GameWindow, _Player);
          Roundy _Roundy=new Roundy(_GameWindow, _Player);
          Boxy_v2 _Boxy_v2=new Boxy_v2(_GameWindow, _Player);
          // setting up the probability to return the robot type..
          if(r < 0.3){
                return _Boxy;
          }else if(r > 0.3 && r < 0.6){
                return _Roundy;
          }else{
                return _Boxy_v2;
          }
    }

    public void DrawGame(){
         // clearing the window..
         _GameWindow.Clear(Color.White); 
         //draw our robots..
         for (int i = 0; i < _Robots.Count; i++){
             _Robots[i].Draw();
             SplashKit.DrawCircle(Color.Blue, _Robots[i].CollisionCircle);
         }
         // drawing our player..
         _Player.DrawPlayer();
        // Number of Lives..
        SplashKit.DrawText($"Lives : {_Lives}", Color.Black, "Ariel", 14, 20, 20);
        SplashKit.DrawText($"Score : {_Score}", Color.Black, "Ariel", 14, 20, 50);
        _GameWindow.Refresh(60);
    }

    // update method..
    public void Update(){
         for (int i = 0; i < _Robots.Count; i++){
              _Robots[i].UpdateRobot();
         }
         if (SplashKit.Rnd() < 0.02){
              _Robots.Add(RandomRobot());
         }
         CheckCollisions();
         // increase _Time by 1 second..
         _Time = _Time.AddSeconds(1);
         // increase score by 1 every second..
         // the below condition will always be true as the difference        between times is always 1 second..
         if (_Time.Second - currentTime.Second == 1){
             _Score += 1;
         }
         if (_Score % 15 == 0){
             _Lives += 1;
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: From the code you've provided the condition `_Time.Second - currentTime.Second == 1` is only true once every minute, `_Score % 15 == 0` is true for a whole minute, and then not for 14. I wonder if, in that first minute, that `_Lives += 1` is being run repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve.  I had to add an update for the current time variable at the top of the loop.  I was under the impression you were updating that somewhere else in the code aside from your Robot constructor and I did not want to skew your activity.  So add to the first line within the update method.

```
    protected DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    // default to a minimum value
    private DateTime _lastTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    public void Update()
    {
        // UPDATE THE TIME HERE based on NOW
        currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        // just FYI, shortcut readability to loop vs indexing loop.
        // An array is an enumerable you can loop through directly
        foreach (var oneRobot in _Robots)
            oneRobot.UpdateRobot();

        // vs what you had
        // for (int i = 0; i < _Robots.Count; i++)
        //{
        //  _Robots[i].UpdateRobot();
        //}

        if (SplashKit.Rnd() < 0.02)
        {
            _Robots.Add(RandomRobot());
        }
        CheckCollisions();


        // if the first time ever in, just set the last time to whatever current IS and get out.
        // you would never increase as score or lives on the first instance as it is basically 0
        if (_lastTime == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            _lastTime = currentTime;
            return;
        }

        // subtracting one date/time 
        // creates a "TimeSpan" object which represents the difference between two date/time fields.
        // if no full second has completed yet, get out.
        if ((currentTime - _lastTime).Seconds < 0)
            return;

        // a second HAS completed since the last measurement. Update Score and Lives
        _Score++;

        if (_Score % 15 == 0)
            _Lives++;

        // NOW, you can adjust, but if its a 1.3 second between cycles, you would be constantly
        // getting farther and farther from actual seconds.  So what I am proposing is to
        // take the last second and just add an absolute one second to it, so when the next
        // real Second cycle is complete, it should properly hit again.
        _lastTime = _lastTime.AddSeconds(1);

    }
```

Comment: @RaghavArora, revised answer and will work.  see revision to set currentTime variable and updated comment of post